# Implement HTML input phone mask XXX-XXX-XXXX

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have an input for US phone numbers that are auto formatting. In other words, as one is typing the cursor automatically advances to the next section and does not allow more than the mask.

I don't want to use any form submitting. And would like to do it simply with input attributes.

Something like this:

```html
<input name="phoneVal" type="text" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX" required>
```

I've seen this implemented in many sites but I can't figure out how to do it. I've been searching for several hours. I guess I am not putting in the correct search question.

Comment: https://imask.js.org/

Comment: I don't want to use third party.

Comment: Changing the type attribute to password should mask the input, but won't give you the auto formatting to phone number

Comment: I don't think this can be done only in HTML, are we missing a tag? In any case, most websites just use a plugin.

Comment: You use three input fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the HTML 5 **pattern** attribute to define a regex to limit the input

```html
<input name="phoneVal" type="text" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required />
```

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: This doesn't add the spacers (-) automatically, and he asked for it to jump to the next segment.

Comment: @vicpermir than complain to the browser developers.  This IS the only solution that doesn't require javascript.

Comment: He also said  "like to do it simply with input attributes".

Comment: Then we agree that it can't be done only with HTML. I didn't mean it in any bad way.

Comment: @vicpermir I did upvote your previous comment saying it coudln't be done with only HTML. This is the HTML solution, it isn't perfect and there is no technical reason why browsers couldn't implement it this way though I'm not sure if the official specification has rendering rules that could prevent this UX.  This isn't a new problem, it has been here for over a decade, pattern is a step forwards but the rendering rules could be improved. Constants values, like the hyphen could easily be automatically added based on the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Simple form validation can be done using HTML5 that will only notifies user on form submission with incorrect values.

pattern attribute uses regular expression.

```
<input name="phoneVal" type="number" min="10" max="10" pattern="RegEx" >
```

If you are looking for more interactivity and more **strict input validation** you will have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it

```
var elementExists = document.getElementById("phoneVal");

if (elementExists){
             document.getElementById('_phoneVal').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
              var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
              e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
            });
        }
```

This only let's user enter values with this format. It automatically fills in 3-3-4 and only allows 10 digits.